# Minted changes text position in slides

Tags: beamer, minted, python

I am making a beamer presentation.
I have this slide:
[image]

The code is

```
\begin{frame}
Il problema viene affrontato utilizzando il metodo degli elementi finiti che spesso però pone numerose restrizioni sulla dimensione della mesh spaziale, richiede l'utilizzo di passi temporali molto piccoli e risulta dispendioso in termini computazionali.\\
\vspace{3mm}
Alternativamente, si potrebbero sfruttare le potenzialità di una rete neurale per fare inferenza sulla soluzione corretta attraverso una interpolazione realizzata con il deep learning.
Tuttavia, anche questo approccio è soggetto a evidenti limiti quando applicato a un problema non lineare. E' necessaria una grande quantità di dati per realizzare il training della rete e il risultato finale può essere molto impreciso.\\
\vspace{3mm}
Per risolvere il problema, evitando i difetti dei due metodi precedenti, ci si propone di utilizzare una rete neurale fisicamente informata, sfruttando la differenziazione automatica per modellare l'equazioni alle derivate parziali definite  dalle leggi fisiche alla base della dinamica del sistema.
\end{frame}
```

Now, if I add \usepackage{minted} at the beginning of my document without changing anything else, the slide changes and becomes like this:
[image]

And this happens to other slides. This is even worst.
Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

How can I avoid this? I need to use minted to insert a python code in one slide. 
Thank you

Comment: Please help us help you by making your code example compilable (a MWE).

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not use an empty line to start a new paragraph?

Comment: you don't show any relevant code but I assume you had a missing `$` (and an error message) after the R^m the unclosed math mode would stop at the `\\ ` if `\\ ` ends the paragraph internally but as beamer restores the normal `\\ `definition the error would be detected later at the next math start.

Answer (score 3):

The version with the space after the line with the forced linebreak is the output I would expect from

```
\\ \vspace{3mm} Alternativamente
```

It will add the space under the line starting with Alternativamente, not before it.

To start a paragraph use a blank line not `\\` and to specify that paragraphs are separated by vertical space use `\setlength\parskip{3mm}`

As it happens then normally in beamer `\\` has a definition that internally forces a paragraph (like the `\\` in a normal `flushleft` environment.) so the form with `\vspace` after `\\` works more or less by accident.

As you note `minted` (somewhat surprisingly) resets `\\` to the standard latex definition.

It is best to mark these as paragraphs not forced line breaks in a single paragraph

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\setlength\parskip{3mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Il problema viene affrontato utilizzando il metodo degli elementi finiti che spesso però pone numerose restrizioni sulla dimensione della mesh spaziale, richiede l'utilizzo di passi temporali molto piccoli e risulta dispendioso in termini computazionali.

Alternativamente, si potrebbero sfruttare le potenzialità di una rete neurale per fare inferenza sulla soluzione corretta attraverso una interpolazione realizzata con il deep learning.
Tuttavia, anche questo approccio è soggetto a evidenti limiti quando applicato a un problema non lineare. E' necessaria una grande quantità di dati per realizzare il training della rete e il risultato finale può essere molto impreciso.

Per risolvere il problema, evitando i difetti dei due metodi precedenti, ci si propone di utilizzare una rete neurale fisicamente informata, sfruttando la differenziazione automatica per modellare l'equazioni alle derivate parziali definite  dalle leggi fisiche alla base della dinamica del sistema.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

The resetting of `\\` is actually by the `lineno` called by `fanvyvrb` which is called by `minted`